# Kubernetes locally via Docker: why do we need port forwarding?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-machine

Trying out Kubernetes on my mac, following [this guide](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html) and using docker-toolbox, I don't understand why I need this step:

```
Note: On OS/X you will need to set up port forwarding via ssh:

boot2docker ssh -L8080:localhost:8080
```

The api server is running with `--net=host` so I should be able to `curl <ip-of-my-docker-machine>:8080` but I got "connection refused". Setting up the port forwarding with ssh solve the problem, but still I don't understand why I can't curl directly the host. Any explanation would be great.

Comment: Kubernetes docs are a bit out of date, with Toolbox the forwarding command would be `docker-machine ssh machine_name -L8080:localhost:8080`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api server only listens on localhost, not the docker-machine ip address.

You can have the host VM forward the requests from the docker-machine ip to localhost with

```
docker-machine ssh default sudo /usr/local/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d $(docker-machine ip) --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

On Macs [docker runs inside the boot2docker virtual machine](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/installation/mac/#learn-the-key-concepts-before-installing). With the `--net=host` option the api server is running on the VM's host network, not your Mac's host network. You can also ssh into the boot2docker VM without port forwarding and curl the API from there, then you just need to download the `kubectl` client while ssh-ed into the VM.

You can't `curl <ip-of-my-docker-machine>:8080` because the Docker VM defaults to denying external traffic and Docker doesn't automatically set up firewall rules to allow traffic when `--net=host` is used. [This article](http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/) goes into more depth.

Comment: Thx, I'm well aware of all this, however, I can easily ping the docker-machine and my docker client running on my mac know where to contact the docker daemon with `DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"`. That is why I'm surprised I can't directly talk to the api server.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. When using host networking Docker won't automatically set up firewall rules to allow incoming traffic. I think this article does a good job of explaining it: http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/

Comment: Thx, still sound weird for me, I guess boot2docker add some restrictions. I'm used to start a ubuntu VM and be able to establish a tcp connection between my host and the VM (with netcat for example). Turns out I can netcat on the docker daemon port (2376) but not on other ports.